# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for 'Instance' and 'Int'

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to apply the PQ formula in Python 2.7.

I'll just post a small bit of the code (where the problem appears to be coming from) here, and I'll link the long version as a pasteboard link.

```
etiquette2=Label(eqGroup,text="ax^2 + bx + c")
etiquette2.pack(padx=10,pady=10,expand=True,fill=BOTH)
etiquette3=Label(eqGroup,text="Please enter a value for a")
etiquette3.pack(padx=10,pady=10,expand=True,fill=BOTH)
input1=Entry(eqGroup,width=10)
input1.pack()
etiquette4=Label(eqGroup,text="Please enter a value for b")
etiquette4.pack(padx=10,pady=10,expand=True,fill=BOTH)
input2=Entry(eqGroup,width=10)
input2.pack()
etiquette5=Label(eqGroup,text="Please enter a value for c")
etiquette5.pack(padx=10,pady=10,expand=True,fill=BOTH)
input3=Entry(eqGroup,width=10)
input3.pack()

a=input1.get()
b=input2.get()
c=input3.get()

a=DoubleVar() #Here I tried to re-type them all to a Float value, but it didn't work apparently
b=DoubleVar()
c=DoubleVar()

temp1=pow(b/2,2) #I tried to do it in steps
temp1=DoubleVar() #And to have the value conversion both before and after the assignment

temp2=sqrt(temp1-c) #But no cookies for me :/
temp2=DoubleVar()

X1=(-b/2)+temp1 #I tried to convert 
X2=(-b/2)-(sqrt(pow(b/2,2)-c)) #This is the PQ formula straight up, which does not work either
```

Pasteboard link to the entire thing: http://pastebin.com/Y77fHwmk

(the text is in Swedish there, because I'm from Sweden. But it's only in a few places, and it won't be relevant to the problem anyways)

Please let me know if you have any ideas^^ I have not managed to fix this in way too long now. Headaches everywhere :/

Traceback is here:

[image: Traceback is here]

Thanks guys :)

Comment: Please show the full traceback here.

Comment: added traceback now^^

Comment: What is `DoubleVar()`? Why are you not using floats? Error is self-explanatory - Python does not know how to divide `DoubleVar()` by `int`.

Comment: @Rogalski: `DoubleVar` is something unique to Tkinter, and is a common way to get values into and out of widgets (though not in the way shown in this post!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only lines that seem to matter are these:

```
b=DoubleVar()
temp1=pow(b/2,2)
```

That's not going to work. What's a `DoubleVar`? If it's not an int or float or double, you're gonna have a bad time.

```
b=DoubleVar()
```

This is not how you cast a variable, if that is your intent.

Rather, try something like this:

```
b = input2.get()
b = float(b)
```

Or in one step:

```
b = float(input2.get())
```

Comment: Well, I have tried to do it all in one (as the last line of the PQ formula shows there), but it just gives the same error anyways.

Comment: I don't think that you have. You are never even executing that code as long as the code is erroring out in advance of it.

Comment: Actually, now the callback is different.
Now it just complains on the line with the PQ Formula, and says "AttributeError: DoubleVar instance has no attribute '__neg__'. Now I tried to move it around to it's own method. A pretty big change, but somehow it fails to recognize the new method even though it is written above it's call point, and is in logical order. I'll post a new pastebin link because it's too long to put in a comment. The new callback says that the global variable equationSolver is not defined (but is the name of the new method)

http://pastebin.com/BxYQVY6x

Comment: Assigning something to DoubleVar() is going to assign that thing to an instance of that class I assume, which is decidedly not what you desire.

Comment: Any time you see `=DoubleVar()` in your code, you are messing up.

Comment: Changed it to your re-typing version of "b = float(input2.get())", but the traceback is still that the global variable is not defined. equationsSolver is not defined somehow, even though it is a defined method?! And I did not make a miss-type or something, because when I mouse over it they both get that underline thingy signaling that they are the exact same

Comment: The new pastebin link is this: http://pastebin.com/k9bx3ckY
The callback is: http://pasteboard.co/2HGGkkUG.png (img)

Comment: You should make a new question, I think we've solved your original problem

Comment: I think the callback might need to be `self.equationsSolver` just glancing at it.

Comment: Your sir are a genius :)
Or I'm retarded. Or both.

It's difficult to get used to Python (I much prefer C++, where I can specify everything from the beginning).

One final problem now though. Because you can't define global variables for just the class, how do you make two different methods have access to the variable? Because now the final problem is that X1 and X2 are in equationSolver, and can not be reached by the final printing thingy at the bottom of equationsWindow. I also can't move the input1/2/3 to equation solver even using .get()

Comment: in c++ I can specify that we have like

class RandomName():
   private:
   int variable, variable2, variable3 #and so on
   public:
   #Insert methods here

Comment: in the `__init__(self)` add `self.X1` and `self.X2` variables and reference them as such everywhere in the class.

Comment: @jgritty: _"Any time you see =DoubleVar() in your code, you are messing up."_ That is simply not true. `DoubleVar()` is a perfectly valid (though often extraneous) thing to do in Tkinter.

Comment: Ah, I see that now, but it probably needs to be done before you do the assignment or input.get(), not after. Also, my comment was specific to THIS code, not all code in the whole world.

Answer (score 1):

These lines in your code make no sense:

```
a=input1.get()
b=input2.get()
c=input3.get()

a=DoubleVar() #Here I tried to re-type them all to a Float value, but it didn't work apparently
b=DoubleVar()
c=DoubleVar()
```

You get values for `a`, `b`, `and`c`from input form but you throw tehm away and replace them with instances of`DoubleVar()`.

Instead try this:

```
a = float(input1.get())
b = float(input2.get())
c = float(input3.get())
```

and delete these lines:

```
a=DoubleVar() 
b=DoubleVar()
c=DoubleVar()
```

Comment: What is this answer adding that wasn't already provided in mine?

Comment: @jgritty I was working on my answer and did not see that you added yours  in between.